# Find new lines in Adobe Brackets

Tags: regex, adobe-brackets

I'm trying to do a find and replace on a file to get rid of line breaks using Adobe Brackets.  However, when I enter `\n` in the search field, even with Regular Expression turned on, it says `No results`.  Is there a way to find newlines within Brackets?

Comment: Interesting, I tried several things like `\n`, `\r\n`, `\r`, `\s`, `\x0D`, `\x0D\x0A`, `\x0A`, `$` and `^` *(I was desperate)*, but nothing worked. I wonder if the search can be done other than line by line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try this:
`(\r\n|\r|\n)`